# how to rerun bootstrap action on AWS EMR when boostrap actions are updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I need to install some python packages on the EMR cluster, and AFAIK, I could write down some `pip install blabla...` commands in EMR's bootstrap actions when CREATING the cluster, and those install-commands will be run when allocating machines for the cluster.

OK, what if the cluster now is created, and later I need to install some other new packages which are not written in the bootstrap actions? I didn't find out any methods for this kind of case, do I HAVE TO re-create a new cluster with the new bootstrap actions?

Answer (score 2):

After the cluster is created, unfortunately, EMR does not provide an API to run a command on ALL NODES.

EMR does have STEP API, where you can run a script on just Master node.

You can either use that STEP API to run a script which can in-turn run a script on all nodes or run a script manually to do so.

There are several options out there like `Ansible , pdsh or simply SSH` etc, . You can find the list of EMR nodes and its hostnames using `YARN -list`